# Sorted List not printed as expected (C)

Tags: c

I tried to make a simpler example of my problem, I hope the code doesn't look too weird. I am trying to make a sorted list. If the input is for ex `wrt`, `er`, `ff`, `fr`, when I try to print the list it says `fr fr fr fr` and I can't understand why.

Unfortunately I can't post the original code, the `struct tit` doesn't make much sense in this example but I don't think that's the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct nodo *link;
typedef struct lista *TLIST;
typedef struct tit *TITOLO;

TLIST LISTinit();
link NEW(TITOLO val, link next);
void LISTinsert(TLIST l, TITOLO val);
void ListPrint(TLIST list);
TLIST caricaFile();

struct tit {
    char nome[20];
};

struct lista {
    link head;
    int n;
};

struct nodo {
    TITOLO val;
    link next;
};

int main() {
    TLIST lista;
    lista = caricaFile();
    ListPrint(lista);
    return 0;
}

TLIST LISTinit() {
    TLIST list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    list->head = NULL;
    list->n = 0;
    return list;
}

link NEW(TITOLO val, link next) {
    link x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    x->next = next;
    x->val = val;
    return x;
}

void LISTinsert(TLIST l, TITOLO val) {
    link x, p;
    l->n++;
    if (l->head == NULL || (strcmp(val->nome, l->head->val->nome) < 0)) {
        l->head = NEW(val, l->head);
        return;
    }
    for (x = l->head->next, p = l->head;
         x != NULL && (strcmp(val->nome, x->val->nome) > 0);
         p = x, x = x->next);
    p->next = NEW(val, x);
}

void ListPrint(TLIST list) {
    link x;
    for (x = list->head; x != NULL; x = x->next)
        printf("%s ", x->val->nome);
    printf("\n");
}

TLIST caricaFile() {
    TLIST list;
    list = LISTinit();
    TITOLO titolo = malloc(sizeof *titolo);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Insert title: ");
        scanf("%s", titolo->nome);
        LISTinsert(list, titolo);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: No problem, if you make an actual [mcve].

Comment: OT: it is a very poor programming practice to hide pointers in a `typedef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in *caricaFile* you save all the read titles in the same location (titolo->nome) so only the last is finaly memorized because you save all the time the same pointer (titolo) in list.

You need to duplicate the val when you save it in the list, rather than to just do `x->val = val;` in NEW, for instance :

```
link NEW(TITOLO val, link next) {
  link x = malloc(sizeof *x);
  x->next = next;

  TITOLO copy = malloc(sizeof (struct tit));

  strcpy(copy->nome, val->nome);
  x->val = copy;
  return x;
}
```

Execution with the new definition of NEW :

```
Insert title: aze
Insert title: qsd
Insert title: wxc
Insert title: iop
aze iop qsd wxc
```

---

It is a very bad idea to make typedef being pointer like TITOLO is because this put the reader in error thinking it is a value rather than a pointer

Comment: Sharp eye! all these pointer typedefs made the code painful to read, not to mention confusing names such as `l` and `NEW`.

Comment: @chqrlie is simple, I did a test and only the last enter name was printed several times, and the O.P. do so many times the same error :-)

Comment: You are correct, the problem statement was a good indication that node values were duplicated somehow. I was reading the code to identify other problems instead of jumping to the probable cause.

Comment: I was thinking about creating an array of pointers like this in caricaFile, so that I don't have to modify NEW
`TITOLO *titolo; titolo =(TITOLO *) malloc(4*sizeof (TITOLO));` but it crashes when the scanf tries to access at `titolo[i]->nome`

Comment: @SimoneSasso is difficult to do throw remarks, open a new question for that if needed.